# how to perform HorizontalPodAutoscaling in Kubernetes based on response time (custom metric) using Prometheus adapter?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, metrics, autoscaling, response-time

Hi everyone,

I have a cluster based on **kubeadm** having 1 master and 2 workers. I have already implemented built-in horizontalPodAutoscaling (based on cpu_utilization and memory) and now i want to perform autoscaling on the basis of custom metrics (**response time** in my case).

I am using **Prometheus Adapter** for custom metrics.And, I could not find any metrics with the name of response_time in prometheus.

1. Is there any metric available in prometheus which scales the application based on response time and what is its name?
2. Whether i will need to edit the default horizontal autoscaling algorithm or i will have to make an algorithm for autoscaling from scratch which could scale my application on the basis of response time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prometheus has only 4 [metric types](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/): **Counter**, **Gauge**, **Histogram** and **Summary**.

I guess **Histogram** is that what you need

> A  *histogram*  samples observations (usually things like request durations or response sizes) and counts them in configurable buckets. It also provides a sum of all observed values.
>
> A histogram with a base metric name of  `<basename>`  exposes multiple time series during a scrape:
>
> - cumulative counters for the observation buckets, exposed as  `<basename>_bucket{le="<upper inclusive bound>"}`
> - the  **total sum**  of all observed values, exposed as  `<basename>_sum`
> - the  **count**  of events that have been observed, exposed as  `<basename>_count`  (identical to  `<basename>_bucket{le="+Inf"}`  above)

### 1.

There is a [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47305424/measure-service-latency-with-prometheus), where you can get a query for latency (response time), so I think this might be useful for you.

### 2.

I dont know if I understand you correctly, but if you want to edit [HPA](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/), you can edit the yaml file, delete previous HPA and create new one instead.

```
kubectl delete hpa <name.yaml>
kubectl apply -f <name.yaml>
```

There is [good article](https://itnext.io/horizontal-pod-autoscale-with-custom-metrics-8cb13e9d475) about [Autoscaling on custom metrics](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale-walkthrough/#autoscaling-on-multiple-metrics-and-custom-metrics) with custom Prometheus Metrics.